# Liquid Oxygen and its paramagnetic properties

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, simulations

How do you calculate the magnetic attraction force on liquid oxygen due to a strong permanent magnet? And if calculating it by hand isn't an ideal solution, which software is the best for handling this simulation?